# Is There Any Time In JavasScript When "!value ? null : value[0]" Would Not Be Equivalent To "value ? value[0] : null"?

Tags: javascript

Is there any time when

```
var result = !value ? null : value[0];
```

would not be equivalent to

```
var result = value ? value[0] : null;
```

Comment: No, there is none. The spec is pretty clear on this one.

Comment: I don't think so. Of course, I have seen `var result = !!value ? value[0] : null;` which might be required in other languages.

Comment: Always! They are both equivalent. I'm lazy to specify why.

Comment: @Daryl: Why do you ask? Is there an actual problem where you think this is the issue?

Comment: @hindmost I'm calling a function that returns an array, or returns null, and I need to get the first item, or just null if it is null

Comment: @sixfingeredman I'v spent 100 time more time in C# that javascript, .  Just making sure I've got my understanding correct of the ToBoolean logic of non boolean objects.

Comment: @Daryl `(myFn() || [])[0]` might be shorter.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I like.  Although that'll return an undefined rather than a null, so I could do `(myFn() || [null])[0]` if I needed a null

Comment: Yes, you could do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding formalism from the language specification to Pointy's answer here.

When you run your code through [the conditional (? :) operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.12) the first thing that happens is that `ToBoolean` is called on the left hand side.

When you do `!value` `ToBoolean` is called on the left hand side, and then ToBoolean on that. The spec is clear on this saying:

> If ToBoolean(GetValue(lref)) is true, then
>
> Let trueRef be the result of evaluating the first AssignmentExpression.
>
> Else
>
> Let falseRef be the result of evaluating the second AssignmentExpression.

So, assuming the JavaScript engine does not contain bugs there are no cases where you'd get a different result in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

It'll never make a difference because the process of interpreting "value" as boolean is identical in both cases. Once that process has been completed, `!` just flips the sense.